# On CircleCI, is it possible to rebuild with a different configuration?

Tags: circleci

We've recently added a `flake8` Python linter test to our CircleCI test commands. However, because it is run before `python manage.py test` to run Django tests, I'm unable to see any actual errors occurring on the test:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
cd lucy-web
source venv/bin/activate
python manage.py compilescss --verbosity 0
python manage.py collectstatic --clear --no-input --verbosity 0
flake8
python manage.py test
./dashboard/tests/test_families.py:1135:13: E128 continuation line under-indented for visual indent
./dashboard/tests/test_families.py:1147:13: E128 continuation line under-indented for visual indent
Exited with code 1
```

I'd like to re-run the tests with an altered configuration in which `python manage.py test` and `flake8` are switched around. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can just run them again in that job, which isn't great, or using CircleCI 2.0 Workflows, great two jobs. One with the "traditional" ordering and another with the reverse order.

Then these two jobs can run in parallel and not really increase the build time.

Respectfully,

Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI